# Scss how to integrate the vendor prefixes for the calc function

Tags: css, sass

I am tired of writing all the vendor prefixes for the `calc` function everytime I am using it :

```
width: calc(100px - 50px);
width: -o-calc(100px - 50px);
width: -moz-calc(100px - 50px);
width: -webkit-calc(100px - 50px);
```

What I usually do, is to create a `mixin` in `sass` which does integrate the vendor prefixes (that example is for `box-shadow`) :

```
@mixin box-shadow($args...) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: $args;
  -moz-box-shadow: $args;
  box-shadow: $args;
}
```

Is there any way to write a similar one for the `calc` function ? (I didn't manage to do it)

Comment: Are you aware of, have you tried https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a direct answer to your question but rather a suggestion that you don't need to add vendor prefixes for `calc` anymore. As far as IE goes, there is no question of the vendor prefix.

About the other browsers, `calc` is now well supported. For further reference, you can check [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

- Firefox supports `calc` from version 4 (current version is 57)
- Chrome supports `calc` from version 19 (current version is 62)
- Opera supports `calc` from version 15 (current version is 48)

It is also supported in Internet Explorer version 9. So I don't think you need to use vendor prefixes as it's completely irrelevant here.

---

### Solution

I've came up with this

```
$props: ("width": "100px - 50px", "height": "100px - 20px");

@mixin calc($props) {
  $vendor-prefixes: ("moz", "o", "webkit");

  @each $prop, $i in $props {
    @each $prefix in $vendor-prefixes {
      #{$prop}: -#{$prefix}-calc(#{$i});
    }

    #{$prop}: calc(#{$i});
  } 
}

body {
  @include calc($props);
}
```

You can try out my solution at [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Here, what am doing is using SASS list feature where it's like an associative array. You build arrays of your properties and feed it to the mixin and it will generate the vendor prefixed version for the same as well.

Note that I've placed non prefixed version at the end of the loop, as it is recommended to place non prefixed versions after prefixed versions.

For more info on [SASS List](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/List.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not, giving you the accepted answer as I still wait to see if anyone has a way of solving this problem in sass.

Comment: @Scipion I can provide you a solution but I honestly don't see any value here

Comment: Well the thing is, I failed to solve a problem from a technical point of view in sass, which, for me, means that I don't master fully the framework and thus am interested how to do it :)

Comment: @Scipion providing a solution, was working on it, am done :)

Comment: @Scipion No prob bro!

Answer (score 0):

The following is pulled from a much larger project for *declarative* instead of *automatic* [vendor prefixes](https://github.com/scss-utilities/vendor-prefixes) of `css` properties or values...

```
@mixin calc($property, $value, $fallback: false) {
  @if $fallback {
    #{$property}: #{$fallback};
  } @else {
    @warn "Consider setting a fallback for #{$property}";
  }
  @include render-vendor-prefixes(
    $property: $property,
    $value: calc(#{$value}),
    $vendor-list: (
      -webkit, // Old - Chrome 19-25, Safari 6
      -moz     // Old - Firefox 4-15
    ),
    $prefix: value,
  );
}
```

> Note the above depends upon two other `scss` files that can be found in the repository's [`lib`](https://github.com/scss-utilities/vendor-prefixes/tree/master/lib) directory.

Example usage

```
@import '_scss/modules/vendor-prefixes/lib/map-vendor-prefixes.scss';
@import '_scss/modules/vendor-prefixes/lib/render-vendor-prefixes.scss';

@import '_scss/modules/vendor-prefixes/calc.scss';



.something {
  @include calc(
    $property: width,
    $value: 100% - 40px,
    $fallback: 85%
  );
}
```

> Note the above `@include` could be *squashed* into a single line, and is expanded just for easier reading.

Example output...

```css
.something {
  width: 85%;
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

While browser support has gotten better for the `calc()` within `css` there still be some that it's not supported, thus the above shows how to set a *fallback* `property` `value` pare within a `@mixin`